# How to specify word styles in clipboard from html page?

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, clipboard, docx

I need to format text with docx marker.

I have in my html `<h1>Title 1</h1>` & `<h2>Title 2</h2>`

When I copy paste this in Word, I keep the bold format and the size but my text is tagged as "Normal" in Word (I lost the semantic information in another words).

I really want to keep or force the style in word. Is there a way to force the word style and put this in the clipboard with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Write your formatted text in Word.  Export it as a Web Page or Single File Web Page.  All the markup needed to preserve formatting when copied from a browser back into Word will be in the exported file(s).  Don't expect it to be terse, but this solution doesn't require JavaScript or any special interaction with clipboard.

Comment: Indeed it works but only with IE. With other browser I lost style (everything is in normal).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether using Java or .NET is an option for you, but for any CSS stylename which matches a Word style, docx4j's ImportXHTML will set that Word style.

When I say "matches a Word style", I mean in the docx the XHTML will be put into.